# Java Scanner with empty delimiter

Tags: java, parsing, lexical-analysis

I'd like to parse some text using an hand-written descending parser. I used `Scanner` with the following delimiter : `"\\s*"`. Unfortunately, the fact that this pattern matches an empty String seems to make every `hasNextFoo` and `nextFoo` matching nothing any more.

The documention doesn't say anything about possibly empty delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

You have some objection to the '+' character?

Are you sure you want to use a regular expression at all, and not just an if statement testing for space characters? You say 'runtime'. Is your data in a string, or coming on a stream, or what?

Comment: Cute. I believe what @bmargulies is trying to say is that the + character will match "at least one", "instead of none or more". Which will prevent it from matching an empty string.

Comment: Yes, because i want to use the scanner as a runtime lexer. In short, I want to be able to ask `scanner.next(pattern)`, that would either return the matched string, or return an exception while not consuming the stream. Spaces should be ignored. If there is a better class to do this than scanner, I would be glad to use it.

Comment: All joking aside, @trashgod's answer is probably what want. You really haven't given us enough background to go on here.

Comment: Good point about more background. FWIW, I added a link to an example.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider [StreamTokenizer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html). Here is an example of using it for one-symbol look-ahead in a [recursive-descent parser](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/enumerated-functions).

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, because i want to use the scanner as a runtime lexer. In short, I want to be able to ask scanner.next(pattern), that would either return the matched string, or return an exception while not consuming the stream. Spaces should be ignored. If there is a better class to do this than scanner, I would be glad to use it.

I cannot think of any off-the-shelf library class that will do this for you.  The normal model of a scanner / lexer is that any invalid character sequence (i.e. one that results in an exception) will be consumed.  So, I think you are going to have to implement your own scanner by hand, taking care to treat the read-ahead characters as unconsumed.  You could do this with a "pushback" reader or (if that model is not convenient) by explicitly buffering the characters yourself with some kind of mark / reset model.  If all you are doing is splitting into tokens separated by one or more spaces, then the pushback reader approach should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use lookbehinds/lookaheads to explicitly define which delimiters are omittable.

For instance this scanner uses whitespaces as a delimiter but doesn't need them between numbers and words:

```
new Scanner("1A.23 4 BC-5")
.useDelimiter("\\s+|(?<=\\d)(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[-+.\\d])");
```

It produces:

```
1
A
.23
4
BC
-5
```

The regex consists of three alternations:

- `\s+` consecutive whitespaces are a delimiter.
- `(?<=\d)(?=[A-Z])` an empty string between a digit and a letter is a delimiter.
- `(?<=[A-Z])(?=[-+.\d])` an empty string between a letter and '-', '+', '.' or
  a digit is a delimiter.

(Note: `\w` can't be used here as it matches digits.)